# Prove a statement for the infinite matrix

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

We are given infinite two dimensional matrix $\{a_{i,j}\}_{i,j=1}^\infty$.
And we know that matrix contain only natural values and each number appears in the matrix exactly 8 times.
Task is to prove that $\exists m,n \in \mathbb{N}\space:\space a_{m,n} > m\cdot n $

We will denote set of i indexes as $I$, set of j indexes as $J$ and set of matrix values as $A$.

Below listed some obvious conclusions which I was able to draw:

Naive exploration of a problem led only to one conclusion:
if $A \sim \mathbb{N}$, than just using ascending order of elements illustrates an counter-example. But $A \nsim \mathbb{N}$ and we have 8 entries of each number. So I'm stuck here.

I don't see any way to prove it. May be I don't know some required theorems. Also an idea crossed my mind that predicate analysis may be the right tool for that problem, but I'm not experienced with it.
So I would appreciate some suggestions and pointers on it.

Comment: Do you mean to show $a_{m,n}>m\cdot n$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Yes, exactly. Already made an edit.

Comment: I'm not quite clear why $|A|\neq\aleph_0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was trying to state that set $A$ is not denumerable. Since there is no bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$, statement $|A| \neq \aleph_0$ is true, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct way to state it. But I don't see why that statement is true to begin with.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok, you planted seed of doubt into my conception. Originally, I supposed that injectivity property fails, since 8 values from $A$ correspond to one value in $\mathbb{N}$. But now I realize, that all 8 of them are equal, so $a_1 \ne a_2 => f(a_1) \ne f(a_2)$. So mapping is bijective and $A$ is countable. I will make an edit.

Comment: Note that $\aleph_0=\aleph_0\cdot 8$, so it's quite easy to see that in fact $A$ is countably infinite. Or if you prefer, note that the map sending $a_{ij}$ to $\langle i,j\rangle$ is a bijection, so there can only be countably many entries in a matrix which has countable index sets; since no value appears infinitely many times, it has to be that there are infinitely many different values. Every infinite subset of a countable set is countably infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume on the contrary that $a_{i,j}\le ij$ for all $i,j$. We shall derive a contradiction from this.
Let $N\in\mathbb N$. For fixed $j\ge1$, we must have $a_{i,j}\le N$ for the $\lfloor \frac Nj\rfloor $ entries $a_{i,j}$ with $1\le i\le\lfloor \frac Nj\rfloor$, i.e.  $a_{1,j},a_{2,j},\ldots,a_{\lfloor \frac Nj\rfloor,j}$.
So if $f(N)$ denotes the number of entries $\le N$ in the matrix, we have just seen that
$$\tag1 f(N)\ge \sum_{j=1}^N\left\lfloor \frac Nj\right\rfloor.$$
On the other hand, by the given condition, we can compute $f(N)$ exactly:
$$\tag2 f(N)=\sum_{j=1}^N 8 = 8N.$$
It is well-known that the harmonic series diverges, hence for some $M\in \mathbb N$ we have
$$\tag3 \sum_{j=1}^M \frac1j>8.$$
Now let $N=M!$, which is clearly $\ge M$. Then because for all $j\le M$ we have $j\mid N$ and hence can simplify $\left\lfloor\frac{N}{j}\right\rfloor = \frac{N}{j}$, we conclude 
$$f(N)\ge \sum_{j=1}^N\left\lfloor \frac Nj\right\rfloor\ge\sum_{j=1}^M\left\lfloor \frac Nj\right\rfloor=\sum_{j=1}^M \frac Nj=N\sum_{j=1}^M\frac1j>8N=f(N),$$
contradiction.

---

*Remark:* The above proof is very wasteful in several places. The first $M$ for which $(3)$ holds is $M=1674$. This makes $N=M!\approx 3.7\cdot 10^{4671}$. On the other hand, by computer check the smallest $N$ for which the inequality $(1)$ contradicts $(2)$ is already $N=2550$. It is not a coincidence that the "best" $N$ is not much larger than the value $1674$ found for $M$. In fact, we can do the last step a bit less wastefull like this:

> There exists $M\in\mathbb N$ with 
>   $$\tag{3'} \sum_{j=1}^M \frac1j>\frac{17}2.$$
>   Let $N=2M$. Then 
>   $$f(N)\ge \sum_{j=1}^N\left\lfloor \frac Nj\right\rfloor\ge\sum_{j=1}^M\left\lfloor \frac Nj\right\rfloor\ge\sum_{j=1}^M\left( \frac Nj-1\right)>\frac{17}2N-M=8N=f(N),$$
>   contradiction.

(Exact numerical checking wll reveal that this leads to $N=5518$, so only twice as big as the "best" possible $N$; of course for the sake of proof these considereatokns are all moot as it doesn't matter if we find an $N$ that is not much larger than the optimum - the problem statement asks us only to show the *existence* of *some* such $N$)

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. I returned to problem and I'm working through it again. I generally get it, but I have slight misunderstanding of inequality (1). Expression on the left side - is a whole amount of entries $a_{i,j}$ that are $\le N$. And I do understand that $8N$ derived from constraint 'each number appears in matrix exactly 8 times', but I can't understand this idea, how and based on what logic you are able to put this upperbound on amount of abovementioned entries $a_{ij}$? Thanks!

Comment: Reading with a bit of distance seems a good idea. The answer needs to be adjusted. Hold on ...